# How to Get element that inside another element by class in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i making HttpWebResponse and getting the HtmlPage with all  data that i need for example table with date info that i need  to save them to array list and save it to xml file

Example of html Page

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="padding5 sorting_1">
<span>01.03.14</span>
</td>
<td class="padding5 sorting_1">
<span>10.03.14</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

my code that not working i using the HtmlAgilityPack,with this i can get  info from span that have class

```
 private static List<string> GetListDataByClass(string HtmlSourse, string Class)
    {
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument DocToParse = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        DocToParse.LoadHtml(HtmlSourse);

        foreach (HtmlNode node in DocToParse.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='" + Class + "']"))
        {
            if(node.InnerText!=null) data.Add(node.InnerText);

        }

        return data;
    }
```

,but in my case td have the class i tryied

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in DocToParse.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='" + Class + "']"))
```

but this not worked

Sow i need to read this data to get the date 01.03.14 and 10.02.14

Sow  any ideas how can i get this dates(01.03.14 and 10.02.14)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the XPath query to:

```
DocToParse.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='" + Class + "']/span")
```

This will select all the spans that are inside a td element with the corresponding class.

Comment: Hmm it's give error --> Object reference not set to an instance of an object